# probability of a set of events from the unconditional probabilities and the probabilities of every pair of events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Obviously, for two events $A$ and $B$, you can not infer $P(A \cap B)$ from $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ if you don't know $P(A|B)$ or $P(B|A)$.

I have three events, $A,B$ and $C$, and I know $P(A), P(B), P(C), P(A \cap B), P(A \cap C), P(B \cap C)$. I suppose, from this, there is no way to compute $P(A \cap B \cap C)$.

Is this right and is there a way to prove it? And how does this generalise to more Events: If you only know the unconditional probabilities of every event, and the probabilities of every pair of events $(P(A \cap B), P(A \cap C), P(A \cap D), P(B \cap C), ...)$, can you show that there is no way of computing the probability of all events together $(P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D ...))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events $A,B,C$ induce a pseudo-partition of $\Omega$ that contains $8$ events.

With a pseudo-partition (unofficial and personal terminology) I mean a collection of disjoint sets that cover $\Omega$ but do not necessarily satisfy the condition that they are not empty.

Elements are the events of the form $E\cap F\cap G$ where $E\in\{A,A^\complement\}$, $F\in\{B,B^\complement\}$ and $G\in\{C,C^\complement\}$.

If $(U_1,U_2,\dots,U_8)$ is a tuple containing these $8$ sets then at first hand we have the equality:$$\sum_{i=1}^8P(U_i)=1$$

To get a situation where the $P(U_i)$ are determined we need $7$ extra conditions.

The knowledge of e.g. $P(A\cap B)$ can be looked at as such a condition.

But knowing $P(A), P(B), P(C), P(A \cap B), P(A \cap C), P(B \cap C)$ is not enough because that only gives us $6$ conditions.

The same approach works if we are dealing more generally with $n$ events.

In that case we need $2^n-1$ extra conditions.

Comment: Why do we need as many conditions as Elements?

Comment: If you have $n$ unkown then you need $n$ (linear) equations to find the unknown. In linear algebra $Ax=b$ can be solved is matrix $A$ can be inverted.

Comment: Yes, but how do I know that I need 8 Probabilities to get 8 equations? Suppose I want to know the real numbers x,y,z, I know a,b, and have the equations x = a, y = b, z = a+b. There I get 3 unknowns from 2 knowns and 3 equations. My problem is, I understand that I know only 7 things and want to know 8 things, but how can I know that it is not possible to combine those 7 things to 8 equations in a way to get the 8 things I want to know?

Comment: In your example with $x,y,z,a,b$ you have built in a relation. It says that the value of $z$ is completely determined by the values of $x$ and $y$. This by $z=x+y$. Such relations that make it possible to solve are actually "equalities in disguise". For the $U_i$ in my answer there is only one relation which is $\sum_{i=1}^8P(U_i)=1$. That's why not $8$ but $8-1$ equations are needed.

Comment: I am not saying that it is always impossible to calculate $P\left(A\cap B\cap C\right)$
on base of $P\left(A\right),P\left(B\right),P\left(C\right),P\left(A\cap B\right),P\left(A\cap C\right),P\left(B\cap C\right)$.
For instance if $P\left(A\cap B\right)=0$ then of course $P\left(A\cap B\cap C\right)=0$.
My answer makes clear that it possible to create situations where
it is not possible. So we can state that in general the knowledge
of these probabilities is not enough. For  an example confirming this see the answer of David.

Answer (score 1):

You need only one counterexample for a disproof.

One way is to suppose a probability space containing several disjoint events $E_1,E_2,E_3,\ldots.$
Assign a probability to each $E_i$ and define each of the events
$A_1,B_1,C_1,A_2,B_2,C_2$ as a union of some collection of the events $E_1,E_2,E_3,\ldots$
in such a way that

\begin{align}
P(A_1) &= P(A_2), \\
P(B_1) &= P(B_2), \\
P(C_1) &= P(C_2), \\
P(A_1 \cap B_1) &= P(A_2 \cap B_2), \\
P(A_1 \cap C_1) &= P(A_2 \cap C_2), \\
P(B_1 \cap C_1) &= P(B_2 \cap C_2), \\
P(A_1 \cap B_1 \cap C_1) &\neq P(A_2 \cap B_2 \cap C_2). \\
\end{align}

Then given only these same probabilities for the first six of the corresponding combinations of $A,$ $B,$ and $C$ it is impossible to know whether the three sets are 
$A_1,B_1,C_1$ or $A_2,B_2,C_2$ and therefore impossible to determine the value of
$P(A \cap B \cap C).$

Of course for a counterexample you must provide the assignments of $A_i,B_i,C_i$ to $E_j$ and the probabilities of the $E_j.$
Some choices of these assignments and probabilities yield cases where
$P(A \cap B \cap C)$ is determined, so you need to choose carefully.